# Defining the argument of a complex number at origin

Tags: complex-numbers

For example:

The locus of satisfying $\arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{3}$ is ?

**My Attempt:**
$$
z =x+iy = |z| \left[ \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) + \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) 
 \right] = |z| \left[ \frac{1}{2} +i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]
\\ 
\implies \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) = \sqrt{3}= \frac{y}{x} \implies y= \sqrt{3}x 
\\
|z|\ge 0 \implies x \ge 0 \quad \& \quad y \ge 0  
\\ 
x=0 \quad \& \quad y=0 \implies \frac{y}{x}=\frac{0}{0} \ne \sqrt{3} \quad \text{($0/0$ is undefined)}
$$
So the locus is a straight line $y=\sqrt{3}x$ in the first quadrant, except at origin.

If $\arg(z)=0$ then
$$
z =x+iy= |z|[ \cos0+i\sin0 ]= |z|+i0 \\
\implies \tan0= \frac{0}{|z|}= 0= \frac{y}{x} \implies y=0 
\\
|z| \ge 0 \implies x \ge 0 \ \ x=0 \quad \& \quad y=0 \implies \frac{y}{x} = \frac{0}{0} = \frac{0}{|z|}
$$
Here the locus is $+x$ axis including the origin. For any value of $\arg(z) \ne 0$, $z$ is not defined at origin.

Does this mean that a complex number $z$ can be defined at origin only if $\arg(z)=0$, i.e. $\arg(0)=0$?

Is my approach correct ?

Comment: The argument for $0+0i$ is undefined.

Comment: However, a complex number $z$ can be at the origin.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the definition of complex numbers at the origin. A complex number $z=x+iy$ is defined for any real values of $x$ and $y$, and this includes $x=y=0$. The problem is with the definition of the arg function, which is not a well-defined function on the entire complex plane. $\text{arg}(z)$ only becomes well-defined if you put restrictions on its domain. One of the restrictions is that $\text{arg}(0)$ is undefined, so $0$ cannot be in the domain of the arg function.

Comment: @LeeMosher are you suggesting that $z$ is defined at origin in the example i have specified above ? since $y=0=\sqrt{3}x=\sqrt{3}*0=0$

Comment: @LeeMosher I hv just edited my original post. hope my doubt is clearly mentioned.

Comment: In the real numbers we already have the matter of the sign of $0$, which allows for writing $0=+0=-0$. This is also $0=0e^{i\pi}=0e^{-i\pi}$. But complex arguments are not limited to $\pm\pi$, so we can say $0=0e^{i\phi}$, no matter the $\phi$. In particular, $0e^\frac{i\pi}{3}=0$.

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont thanx. so is it wrong to say that locus of $z$ is a straight line y=\sqrt{3}x in the first quadrant, except at origin ?, since $z$ is also defined at origin.

Comment: Hmm... WolframAlpha seems to exclude 0 when $arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{3}$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg(z)%3Dpi%2F3.
but it includes 0 when $arg(z)=0$
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg(z)%3D0
Is that consistent?

Comment: There is something tricky here... Forget about complex numbers for a while and check on WA what $sgn(0)$ is and the locus of $sgn(x)>0$ against $sgn(x)>=0$, which have the same result but it should be different according to the result of $sgn(0)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont  I think as per WolframAlpha, for $\arg(z)\neq{0}$ excludes $0$, so it is a straight line $y=\sqrt{3}x$ in the first quadrant except at origin for $\arg(z)=\pi/3$. And if $arg(z)=0$ then it seems to include $0$. s that correct ?. Does this means that $z=0+0i$ is true only for $\arg(0)=0$ or it is undefined at $z=0$? is it due to my last argument in my original post ?

Comment: @LeeMosher can't we say that $arg(0)=0$, since $z$ is undefined at the origin for any other value of $arg(z)$ ?

Comment: Defining $\text{arg}(0)=0$ would guarantee that it is discontinuous unless the domain consists of only the non-negative $x$-axis. Which would make it a pretty useless definition. But yeah, you can define anything you like. The trick is making definitions that are useful.

Comment: @LeeMosher my comment was in regard to what WolframAlpha seems to provide as suggested by Jaume Oliver Lafont

Comment: I would not use WolframAlpha as my guide to defining the arg function.